# Linux kills process when calling execv()/execve()

Tags: linux, embedded-linux, su, execve

The program is executed on an embedded Linux (Kernel version: 3.4.0). Before calling `execve()`, `setgid()` and `setuid()` are also called to switch to another user (`tstuser`). The user exists, the necessary entries are found in `/etc/[passwd && group && shadow]`. The command `su tstuser` (by `root`) also simply reports "Killed". Resource limits already checked with `getrlimit()` previously, all seems to be OK. No error log (not a single line) found in `dmesg` && `/var/log/messages`.

What can be the cause? How can I get the kernel to be more verbose? Any idea or further places to investigate?

Here is the complete code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pwd.h>

int main( int argc, char *argv[] ) {
  char *newargv[] = { NULL, NULL };
  char *newenviron[] = { NULL };

  if ( argc != 2 ) {
    fprintf( stderr, "Usage: %s <file-to-exec>\n", argv[0] );
    exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
  }
  newargv[0] = argv[1];

  struct passwd * pw;
  if ( ( pw = getpwnam( "tstuser" ) ) == NULL ) {
    fprintf( stderr, "ERROR: the specified user '%s' does not exist\n", "tstuser" );
    exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
  }
  else {
    if ( setgid( pw->pw_gid ) != 0 ) {
      fprintf( stderr, "ERROR: setgid() to %d failed\n", pw->pw_gid );
      exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }
    else if ( setuid( pw->pw_uid ) != 0 ) {
      fprintf( stderr, "ERROR: setuid() to %d failed\n", pw->pw_uid );
      exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }
  }

  execve( argv[1], newargv, newenviron );
  perror( "execve" );
  exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
}
```

The complete strace output:

```
~# strace ./execve /bin/ls
execve("./execve", ["./execve", "/bin/ls"], [/* 13 vars */]) = 0
brk(0)                                  = 0x145d000
uname({sys="Linux", node="sagVED_A", ...}) = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat64(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=4666, ...}) = 0
mmap2(NULL, 4666, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0xb6fb5000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/lib/tls/v5l/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/lib/tls/v5l", 0xbee6b468)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/tls/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/lib/tls", 0xbee6b468)          = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/v5l/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/lib/v5l", 0xbee6b468)          = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\1\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0(\0\1\0\0\0\354\225\262F4\0\0\0"..., 512) = 512
fstat64(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=1245200, ...}) = 0
mmap2(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xb6fb4000
mmap2(0x46b10000, 1284496, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x46b10000
mprotect(0x46c3c000, 32768, PROT_NONE)  = 0
mmap2(0x46c44000, 16384, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x12c) = 0x46c44000
mmap2(0x46c48000, 6544, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x46c48000
close(3)                                = 0
mmap2(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xb6fb3000
set_tls(0xb6fb34c0, 0xb6fb3b98, 0x46b07058, 0xb6fb34c0, 0x46b07058) = 0
mprotect(0x46c44000, 8192, PROT_READ)   = 0
mprotect(0x46b06000, 4096, PROT_READ)   = 0
munmap(0xb6fb5000, 4666)                = 0
brk(0)                                  = 0x145d000
brk(0x147e000)                          = 0x147e000
socket(PF_FILE, SOCK_STREAM|SOCK_CLOEXEC|SOCK_NONBLOCK, 0) = 3
connect(3, {sa_family=AF_FILE, sun_path="/var/run/nscd/socket"}, 110) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
close(3)                                = 0
socket(PF_FILE, SOCK_STREAM|SOCK_CLOEXEC|SOCK_NONBLOCK, 0) = 3
connect(3, {sa_family=AF_FILE, sun_path="/var/run/nscd/socket"}, 110) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
close(3)                                = 0
open("/etc/nsswitch.conf", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fcntl64(3, F_GETFD)                     = 0x1 (flags FD_CLOEXEC)
fstat64(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=465, ...}) = 0
mmap2(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xb6fb6000
read(3, "# /etc/nsswitch.conf\n#\n# Example"..., 4096) = 465
read(3, "", 4096)                       = 0
close(3)                                = 0
munmap(0xb6fb6000, 4096)                = 0
open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat64(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=4666, ...}) = 0
mmap2(NULL, 4666, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0xb6fb5000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/lib/libnss_compat.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\1\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0(\0\1\0\0\0\340\r\0\0004\0\0\0"..., 512) = 512
fstat64(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=30524, ...}) = 0
mmap2(NULL, 62060, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0xb6fa3000
mprotect(0xb6fa9000, 32768, PROT_NONE)  = 0
mmap2(0xb6fb1000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x6) = 0xb6fb1000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/lib/libnsl.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\1\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0(\0\1\0\0\0p/\361F4\0\0\0"..., 512) = 512
fstat64(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=73264, ...}) = 0
mmap2(0x46f10000, 112464, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x46f10000
mprotect(0x46f21000, 28672, PROT_NONE)  = 0
mmap2(0x46f28000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x10) = 0x46f28000
mmap2(0x46f2a000, 5968, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x46f2a000
close(3)                                = 0
mprotect(0x46f28000, 4096, PROT_READ)   = 0
mprotect(0xb6fb1000, 4096, PROT_READ)   = 0
munmap(0xb6fb5000, 4666)                = 0
open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat64(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=4666, ...}) = 0
mmap2(NULL, 4666, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0xb6fb5000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/lib/libnss_nis.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/tls/v5l/libnss_nis.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/usr/lib/tls/v5l", 0xbee6b340)  = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/tls/libnss_nis.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/usr/lib/tls", 0xbee6b340)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/v5l/libnss_nis.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/usr/lib/v5l", 0xbee6b340)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/libnss_nis.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/usr/lib", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=8456, ...}) = 0
munmap(0xb6fb5000, 4666)                = 0
open("/etc/passwd", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fcntl64(3, F_GETFD)                     = 0x1 (flags FD_CLOEXEC)
_llseek(3, 0, [0], SEEK_CUR)            = 0
fstat64(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=848, ...}) = 0
mmap2(NULL, 848, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, 3, 0) = 0xb6fb6000
_llseek(3, 848, [848], SEEK_SET)        = 0
munmap(0xb6fb6000, 848)                 = 0
close(3)                                = 0
setgid32(1001)                          = 0
setuid32(1001)                          = 0
execve("/bin/ls", ["/bin/ls"], [/* 0 vars */] <unfinished ...>
+++ killed by SIGKILL +++
Killed
```

Comment: Try it without the setuid/setgid. The problem might be some obscure permission thing, not execve itself.  Also, might try passing at least argv[0] to the new process.

Comment: Works here. (using `sudo ./a.out /bin/ls`  ) Maybe selinux is involved? What does syslog say?

Comment: Without setuid/setgid it works. Without setuid also works. The posted original app works on any other platforms available around. It only does not work on this specific embedded platform (KaRo TX28 SOC, Poky (Yocto) distribution, 3.4.0 kernel.

Comment: SELinux is not used. The most disturbing thing is, there is not a single log line in syslog or dmesg. When OOM happens and the kernel kills a process on this very same platform dmesg shows what happened. In the current situation 70 / 128 MB memory is available.

Comment: After decorating the kernel source with printk() messages, it can be seen now that the SIGKILL comes from fs/binfmt_elf.c: https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v3.4/source/fs/binfmt_elf.c#L812 What can be the reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was: the value of the kernel config paramter CONFIG_DEFAULT_MMAP_MIN_ADDR was set to 65536.

When page size is 64k, 0x8000(32k) and CONFIG_DEFAULT_MMAP_MIN_ADDR are both at the 0th page, which is causing non-root user cannot run the binary built by the toolchain, e.g. busybox (source: http://mkl-note.blogspot.hu/2011/06/configdefaultmmapminaddr.html).

In cap_file_mmap() (see https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v3.4/source/security/commoncap.c#L960) cap_capable() rejected the memory mapping requested by load_elf_binary() at https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v3.4/source/fs/binfmt_elf.c#L809 (through a chain of other function calls).

Setting CONFIG_DEFAULT_MMAP_MIN_ADDR to 32768 or smaller solved the issue.

Comment: Or better, copy the default linker script and edit to link at a base address of at least 64K, so the zero page can remain unmapped to catch NULL derefs, and so you're not wasting half a page filled with zeros before your .text section.